# iOS: Issue in updatating devicetoken after initial rejection of permission for push notification?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I have made an Application that gives push notification. There is an issue with devicetoken updation. When the user has given permission for push notifications as soon as the app is installed, the devicetoken is being updated. But the scenario where the user rejects the permission after the App is installed and later grants the permission in the settings, then the device token is still showing null.

I would appreciate it if someone could help me on how can I get the device token when the user grants the permission for push notifications after initially rejecting permission when the App is installed.

This is the code I have implemented.

```
    func registerForPushNotification(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // set notification types
    let types: UIUserNotificationType = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: types, categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
    // register
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}

// success fetching device token
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

    let tokenChars = (deviceToken as NSData).bytes.bindMemory(to: CChar.self, capacity: deviceToken.count)
    var deviceTokenString = ""

    for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
        deviceTokenString += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [tokenChars[i]])
    }

    print("Device token \(deviceTokenString)")

    // register device token
    Service.sharedService.registerDeviceToken(deviceTokenString, completion: { (error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print("Device token not registered: \(error.localizedDescription)")

        } else {
            print("Device token registered!")
        }
    })

}
// failed fetching device token
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("Error registering for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check permission in applicationWillEnterForeground

Sample code for more reference

### swift 2.0

```
optional func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
let notificationType = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()!.types
if notificationType == UIUserNotificationType.None {
        // Push notifications are disabled in setting by user.
    }else{
  // Push notifications are enabled in setting by user.
// need to call again register remote notification code
// set notification types

  let types: UIUserNotificationType = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: types, categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
    // register
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

}
}
```